Why does CDKTF / terraform think there is nothing to destroy?
A simple command like
cdktf destroy DatasetCrawlerStack

says there is nothing to destroy
DatasetCrawlerStack  Initializing the backend...
DatasetCrawlerStack  Initializing provider plugins...
                     - Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
DatasetCrawlerStack  - Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v5.49.0
DatasetCrawlerStack  Terraform has been successfully initialized!
                     
                     You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
                     any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
                     should now work.

                     If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
                     rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
                     commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
DatasetCrawlerStack  No changes. No objects need to be destroyed.

                     Either you have not created any objects yet or the existing objects were
                     already deleted outside of Terraform.
DatasetCrawlerStack  
                     Destroy complete! Resources: 0 destroyed.

but when I go to deploy
cdktf deploy DatasetCrawlerStack 

I get an already exists error?
DatasetCrawlerStack  Initializing the backend...
DatasetCrawlerStack  Initializing provider plugins...
                     - Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
DatasetCrawlerStack  - Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v5.49.0
DatasetCrawlerStack  Terraform has been successfully initialized!
                     
                     You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
                     any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
                     should now work.

                     If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
                     rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
                     commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
DatasetCrawlerStack  Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan.
                     Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
                       + create

                     Terraform will perform the following actions:

                       # aws_glue_crawler.REDACTED-cdktf-crawler (REDACTED-cdktf-crawler) will be created
                       + resource "aws_glue_crawler" "REDACTED-cdktf-crawler" {
                           + arn           = (known after apply)
                           + database_name = "REDACTED"
                           + id            = (known after apply)
                           + name          = "REDACTED-cdktf-crawler"
                           + role          = "arn:aws:iam::822795565729:role/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole-REDACTED-test-datasets"
                           + tags_all      = (known after apply)

                           + s3_target {
                               + path = "s3://REDACTED-lake/_datasets/_latest/"
                             }
                         }

                     Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
                     
                     Do you want to perform these actions?
DatasetCrawlerStack  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
                       Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.
DatasetCrawlerStack  Enter a value: yes
DatasetCrawlerStack  aws_glue_crawler.REDACTED-cdktf-crawler: Creating...
DatasetCrawlerStack  ╷
                     │ Error: creating Glue Crawler (REDACTED-cdktf-crawler): AlreadyExistsException: 822795565729:REDACTED-cdktf-crawler already exists
                     │ 
                     │   with aws_glue_crawler.REDACTED-cdktf-crawler (REDACTED-cdktf-crawler),
                     │   on cdk.tf.json line 35, in resource.aws_glue_crawler.REDACTED-cdktf-crawler (REDACTED-cdktf-crawler):
                     │   35:       }
                     │ 
                     ╵


0 Stacks deploying     1 Stack done     0 Stacks waiting
Invoking Terraform CLI failed with exit code 1

i think my code is simple-ish
import boto3
from cdktf import S3Backend, TerraformStack
from cdktf_cdktf_provider_aws import provider,glue_crawler
# from imports.aws.glue_crawler import GlueCrawler
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings


class StackConfig(BaseSettings):
    """Settings configured via environment variables."""

    aws_region: str = "us-east-2"
    crawler_role: str = "arn:aws:iam::822795565729:role/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole-REDACTED-test-datasets"
    database_name: str = "REDACTED_datalake"
    s3_target_path: str = "s3://REDACTED-lake/_datasets/_latest/"


class DatasetMetadataCrawlerStack(TerraformStack):
    def __init__(self, scope, id, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        config = StackConfig()

        provider.AwsProvider(self, f"{id}-AwsProvider", region=config.aws_region)
        boto3.client("sts").get_caller_identity()["Account"]
        account_alias = boto3.client("iam").list_account_aliases()["AccountAliases"][0]

        state_bucket = f"{account_alias}-tfstate-{config.aws_region}"
        state_key = "a2p-commons/dataset_metadata_crawler/terraform.tfstate"

        S3Backend(
            scope,
            bucket=state_bucket,
            key=state_key,
            encrypt=True,
            region=config.aws_region,
        )

        glue_crawler.GlueCrawler(
            self, 
            "REDACTED-cdktf-crawler",
            name="REDACTED-cdktf-crawler",
            role=config.crawler_role,
            database_name=config.database_name,
            s3_target=[
                glue_crawler.GlueCrawlerS3Target(
                    path=config.s3_target_path,
                )
            ],
        )


Any help would be greatly appreciated. Am I thinking about terraform/cdktf the wrong way?
It is asking me to add more details. So I am putting text here. However, I think that the question has already been adequately described. Hopefully this is enough text to allow for posting. Thank you for your time.

I accidentally deleted the .tfstate file. Apparently terraform/cdktf use that to assess state - it is not retrieved dynamically from aws

You could configure a Terraform backend to store the state in an S3 bucket in your AWS account, so you don't have to worry about accidently deleting your local state file. But you really need to understand how Terraform state works and why there is a state file, in order to effectively use Terraform. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state

Thanks for the suggestion about the backend. I have added reading that documentation to my backlog.
